# Looking to Resolve Inexpensive Bike (Riverside 500) Compatibility Issues with Elite Suito Trainer

Tags: compatibility

I have an Elite Suito trainer, but am now struggling to find the cheapest bike that is compatible with it.

Is the B'Twin Riverside 500 (https://www.decathlon.in/p/8389412/hybrid-india/adult-hybrid-cycle-riverside-500-grey-red) compatible with it? The Suito manual says "Suito is compatible with bikes with 130 to 135 mm hubs with 5 mm diameter quick release", but I'm having trouble finding the hub size on the Riverside 500? I'm also not sure if the cassette is Shimano compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's compatible.

The upper versions of the Riverside (same frame) are sold with Mavic wheels that have 135mm hubs. The cassette is Shimano compatible.

Please however note that the range (difference between upper and lower gears) is very limited on the Riverside series. No problem if you want to use the ERG mode, but this can be a problem if you want to simulate "real" tracks.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be going to a physical store to see what else they have in stock. Is there a way to gauge the range from tech specs, or is this just something one knows / should ask others who've used the bike?

Comment: The range can be computed from the specs. On a single chainring bike, it's simply the division of the number of tooth of the biggest sprocket of the cassette by the smallest sprocket. 36/11=320%. 500% are common for MTBs and road bikes.